# What is the use of "in" and "on"?

Tags: prepositions

Is it "in" or "on "?

Where is the ball?

It's in the pool.

Note that : The pool is full of water and the ball above the water.

Answer (score 1):

The preposition *at* would denote its *location* but the context you clarified is that the ball is *in.* That said,

> the ball is *in* the swimming pool.

But yes, ***if*** the context is *water,* you use 'on.'

> the ball is *on* the water or *floating* on the...

Using prepositions for a swimming pool is interesting. Further, watching is recommended  here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O8qiHff4VVg

Comment: Thanks , Can I say : The ball is on the water in the swimming pool.

Comment: You can but it'd be, in this context, redundant.

Answer (score 1):

People often think that "on" means "on top of" or "above", but it actually means "located at the surface".

> There's a fly on the wall and a spider on the ceiling.

The fly is not above the wall and the spider is actually below the ceiling!

> I have a mole on my arm.

Depending on how my arm is positioned, the mole could be on top, on the bottom, or at the side of my arm.

So is the ball on the pool? Assuming the pool is full to the top with water, the ball can only be touching the side edge of the pool (the border around it). The ball is actually below the level of the top, so it is in(side) the pool. This is the same whether it's a beach ball which floats, or a golf ball that sinks.

The other thing to consider is that for nouns that represent containers, we usually say "in" unless the other object is outside it.

> There's a fly **on** my glass. (it's crawling on the outside)
>
> There's a fly **in** my glass. (it's crawling on the inside or swimming in my drink)
>
> The sugar is **on** the shelf **in** the cupboard. (a shelf isn't a container but a cupboard is)